# Link pivot table in Yii2

Tags: controller, yii2, many-to-many, pivot-table

I have one many to many relationship model. There are two tables user and entity. and I have created one another table user_entity to apply many-to-many relationship.

user.php

```
public function getEntities()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Entity::class, ['id' => 'entity_id'])
        ->viaTable('drs_user_entity', ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

entity.php

```
public function getUsers() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, ['id' => 'user_id'])
      ->viaTable('drs_user_entity', ['entity' => 'id']);
}
```

Now if user changes it entities, how can I make changes in user_entity table?

Note: I have already tried regular first delete and then add new data to user_entity. and it's an API controller, I send entity details in this format:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you try this? Connect to pivot with hasMany then users from there. It will probably solve your problem this way.

```
$entityModels[0]->pivot->users;
```